# Force rename table column name (case spelling)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We want to rename old upper-case fieldnames in our mssql db to "Pascal-Case".

Our problem is, there are a lot of dependencies on those columns.

For example:

```
sp_RENAME 'Object.OBJECTID' , 'ObjectID', 'COLUMN'
```

When executing the above SQL the following error is returned:

> Object 'Object.OBJECTID' cannot be renamed because the object participates in enforced dependencies.

Because we are only change the character case, we do not really break deps. Is there a way to force this operation?

Comment: Changing the case of characters in a of an object **can** break dependencies; depending on your collation. if you are using a case sensitive collation (Such as `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS`), then you could have two objects with different cases in their names. For example, in a database I have with the aforementioned collation, this SQL is perfectly legal: `CREATE TABLE test (id int, ID int, iD int, Id int);` As a result, SQL Server will not allow you to change the name of a object if it has dependencies.

Comment: Not unless you remove all the dependencies first. Remember that in a case sensitive collation OBJECTID and ObjectID are not the same thing. In a case sensitive collation you can a single table with those two columns but will fail in a case insensitive collation. This is why that error is happening.

Comment: @Larnu seems we posted nearly the same at nearly the same time. :)

Comment: @SeanLange Indeed! Think I beat you by about 2 seconds. :P

Comment: Yes, but our database is case insensitive. So it would really safe me a lot of work if we can change this without dropping all dependencies, with is almost impossible on our db.

Comment: Even if your database is using a case insensitive collation, that doesn't affect the requirement that a column with dependencies cannot be renamed. The rule applies regardless.

Comment: Since you are on a case insensitive collation why does it really matter if the capitalization is user friendly? I agree that Pascal case is easier to read though.

Comment: @SeanLange It's mainly about readability.

Comment: Well I guess you have to decide if the readability is worth the effort of removing all the dependencies on each object so you can rename them. I understand the frustration of objects that are difficult to read. Maybe you can generate a script of all the dependencies first so you can easily recreate them?

Comment: Once I had to change the default collation of a database. Other problem but similar issues... I did the following: 1) take a backup 2) throw away all dependencies 3) Use a compare tool (in this case it was RedGate) which created a script and re-created all the missing objects.

Comment: In your case this would mean: Create the script to re-create all dependencies. After this rename your columns and hope that the script will run (due to an insensitive collation). To be honest: I would not do this...

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices to solve this problem:

**Manual Method**

1. Use SQL Server Management Studio, View dependencies for the
   object you want to rename
2. Update the DDL script for the dependent object with the new name
   of the renamed object
3. Repeat steps #1 and #2 for all dependent objects, individually
4. If you want to rename more than 1 object, repeat the steps 1 through 3

**Automatic Method**

You can simply use third party applications such as [ApexSQL](https://www.apexsql.com/) and use it's `Safe Rename` feature.([Watch the tutorial video here](https://tv.apexsql.com/apexsql-refactor-how-to-safely-rename-database-objects-without-breaking-dependencies/)). You can also use [RedGate](https://www.red-gate.com/)'s `Smart Rename` fetaure too.([Read more here](https://documentation.red-gate.com/sp6/refactoring-your-code/renaming-objects))